# How can I move the toolbar if its holder is out of screen?

Tags: qgis, toolbar

[image: HOLDER IS OUT]

While I was editing the toolbar, the holder stayed out of the screen. so I can't move it. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you resize your QGIS window and drag the holder back?

Comment: I resized the QGIS window however the problematic toolbar is not attached like others. I can't reach the holder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *Plugins* > *Python Console*, try typing the following:

```
qgis.utils.iface.layerToolBar().move(5,5)
```

It should move the toolbar shown in your image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @lunata - Awesome! Glad you got it working again :)

Answer (score 2):

Another trick you can use in situations like this is to temporarily change the size/resolution of your desktop in the operating system options (typically accessible by right-clicking the desktop). You can increase the resolution which should bring off-screen features back on, and sometimes if you decrease the resolution all programs/windows are forced back on-screen to fit or desktop scrolling is enabled. Once you can see the window/toolbar and move it back 'in range', you can then set your desktop back to what it originally was.