# QGIS windows stuck off screen and can't get it back, locks entire application in the meantime

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

OS Ubuntu 16.04

QGIS version 2.18.16

I have a problem where if I try to open any windows that spawns from "Rule-based" symbology in the style menu. Trying to change the rules by double clicking on them, or to change the symbology results in the application getting locked, I am assuming because the window that is spawned is somehow off-screen. I have no idea how this even happened because I am only using one screen, and it was working earlier, but all of a sudden it does not.

The only way to get control back is to manually kill QGIS via the terminal and restart it.

The only place this seems to happen is when I try to spawn the windows from the "Rule-based" symbology menu, other symbology menus (categorized, single symbol etc.) do not cause a problem (spawned window appears on-screen)

[This solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151952/how-can-i-move-the-toolbar-if-its-holder-is-out-of-screen) did not help because it is for a toolbar and not a window.

Comment: What about using the **Layer Styling Dock** which is the first button at the top of your _Layers Panel_? This should prevent most windows from appearing as it is mostly contained within the dockwidget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have looked harder... This exact bug is documented at https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15317

The solution is apparently to delete the `qgis` folder in `~/.config/`, however it is worth noting that my folder was called `QGIS`, not `qgis`.

Also note that this will reset the interface to its initial state, so you will lose all database connections, favourite folder paths, toolbar layouts etc.

Answer (score 1):

Had a comparable issue on Windows 11, QGIS 3.28.2-Firenze, AMD onboard graphics. I came here when looking for a solution, so maybe someone else will too. The issue occured after the use of a projector as second monitor.

Problem after the start of QGIS:
The bottom of the main window was lower than the edge of the display, size of the height could not be adjusted to a smaller size. Attempting to enlarge the window upwards will cause it to disappear irretrievably.

Solution worked for me:
Edit QGIS3.ini (as mentioned in the answer of Dan).
Delete the lines starting with "state=" and "geometry=" under [UI]. Restart QGIS.

Comment: @wfgeo If editing the QGIS3.ini file rather than deleting doesn't loose all configuration this a better answer than the accepted one

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The same just happened to me on `Windows 10 version 21H2`, `QGIS version LTR 3.22.11-Białowieża`.

When I open the Project Properties in QGIS the bottom half of the Properties window is under the Windows task bar. When I attempt to adjust the size of the window it completely disappears under the task bar, rendering the QGIS program unusable.

[image]

To solve the issue I had to delete the configuration settings file (`QGIS3.ini`) in the AppData folder of my PC.

Press Windows key + R to open the search box, type `%appdata%`.

The configuration settings file is in: `AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS`

Delete the file and restart QGIS.

[image]

The problem with this solution, as mentioned, is that you loose all your saved QGIS configurations (plugins, database links, etc). If someone has a better solution please reply.